# How to add pattern lock functionality code in android ??

Tags: android

i have gone through this link https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/ to apply pattern functionality in my application. But i am facing some issues, I have created continue button to move to next screen for confirming the pattern but its not working at all. I want that when user starts to draw the pattern on the first screen continue button should start working but its not working so. Please tell me the solution.I am attaching my MainActivity.java code.
Thanks in advance

```
      package com.example.lock_pattern;
      import com.example.lock_pattern.prefs.DisplayPrefs;
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      private static final String CLASSNAME = MainActivity.class.getName();
      public static final String ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN = CLASSNAME
      + ".create_pattern";


      public static final String ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN = CLASSNAME
      + ".compare_pattern";


      public static final String ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA = CLASSNAME
      + ".verify_captcha";

 * If you use {@link #ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN} and the user fails to "login"
      public static final int RESULT_FAILED = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1;

 * If you use {@link #ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN} and the user forgot his/ her
      public static final int RESULT_FORGOT_PATTERN = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 2;

      * If you use {@link #ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN}, and the user fails to "login"
      public static final String EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT = CLASSNAME + ".retry_count";

      * Sets value of this key to a theme in {@code R.style.Alp_Theme_*}. Default
      public static final String EXTRA_THEME = CLASSNAME + ".theme";

      * Key to hold the pattern. It must be a {@code char[]} array.
      public static final String EXTRA_PATTERN = CLASSNAME + ".pattern";

 * You can provide an {@link ResultReceiver} with this key. The activity
       public static final String EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER = CLASSNAME
        + ".result_receiver";

 * Put a {@link PendingIntent} into this key. It will be sent before
public static final String EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_OK = CLASSNAME
        + ".pending_intent_ok";

 * Put a {@link PendingIntent} into this key. It will be sent before
public static final String EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_CANCELLED = CLASSNAME
        + ".pending_intent_cancelled";

 * You put a {@link Intent} of <i>{@link Activity}</i> into this extra. The
public static final String EXTRA_INTENT_ACTIVITY_FORGOT_PATTERN = CLASSNAME
        + ".intent_activity_forgot_pattern";

 * Helper enum for button OK commands. (Because we use only one "OK" button
private static enum ButtonOkCommand {
    CONTINUE, FORGOT_PATTERN, DONE
}// ButtonOkCommand

 * Delay time to reload the lock pattern view after a wrong pattern.
private static final long DELAY_TIME_TO_RELOAD_LOCK_PATTERN_VIEW = DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;

/*
 * FIELDS
 */
private int mMaxRetry;
private boolean mAutoSave;
private IEncrypter mEncrypter;
private int mMinWiredDots;
private ButtonOkCommand mBtnOkCmd;
private Intent mIntentResult;
private int mRetryCount = 0;

/*
 * CONTROLS
 */
private TextView mTextInfo;
private LockPatternView mLockPatternView;
private View mFooter;
private Button mBtnCancel;
private Button mBtnConfirm;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d(CLASSNAME, "ClassName = " + CLASSNAME);

    /*
     * EXTRA_THEME
     */

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_THEME))
        setTheme(getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_THEME,
                R.style.Alp_Theme_Dark));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oncreate", 7000).show();
    mMinWiredDots = DisplayPrefs.getMinWiredDots(this);
    mMaxRetry = DisplayPrefs.getMaxRetry(this);
    mAutoSave = SecurityPrefs.isAutoSavePattern(this);

    /*
     * Encrypter.
     */
    char[] encrypterClass = SecurityPrefs.getEncrypterClass(this);
    if (encrypterClass != null) {
        try {
            mEncrypter = (IEncrypter) Class.forName(
                    new String(encrypterClass), false, getClassLoader())
                    .newInstance();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new InvalidEncrypterException();
        }
    }

    mIntentResult = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, mIntentResult);

    initContentView();
}// onCreate()

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d(CLASSNAME, "onConfigurationChanged()");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    initContentView();
}// onConfigurationChanged()

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onKeyDown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        /*
         * Use this hook instead of onBackPressed(), because onBackPressed()
         * is not available in API 4.
         */
        finishWithNegativeResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}// onKeyDown()

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d(CLASSNAME, "onDestroy()");
}// onDestroy()

/**
 * Initializes UI...
 */
private void initContentView() {
    /*
     * Save all controls' state to restore later.
     */

      CharSequence infoText = mTextInfo != null ? mTextInfo.getText() : null;
    Boolean btnOkEnabled = mBtnConfirm != null ? mBtnConfirm.isEnabled()
            : null;
    LockPatternView.DisplayMode lastDisplayMode = mLockPatternView != null ? mLockPatternView
            .getDisplayMode() : null;
    List<Cell> lastPattern = mLockPatternView != null ? mLockPatternView
            .getPattern() : null;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UI.adjustDialogSizeForLargeScreen(getWindow());

    mTextInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alp_textview_info);
    mLockPatternView = (LockPatternView) findViewById(R.id.alp_view_lock_pattern);

    mFooter = findViewById(R.id.alp_viewgroup_footer);
    mBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alp_button_cancel);
    mBtnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alp_button_confirm);

    /*
     * LOCK PATTERN VIEW
     */

    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.alp_is_large_screen)) {
        int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.alp_lockpatternview_size);
        LayoutParams lp = mLockPatternView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = size;
        lp.height = size;
        mLockPatternView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    /*
     * Haptic feedback.
     */
    boolean hapticFeedbackEnabled = false;
    try {
        hapticFeedbackEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0) != 0;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        /*
         * Ignore it.
         */
    }
    mLockPatternView.setTactileFeedbackEnabled(hapticFeedbackEnabled);

    mLockPatternView.setInStealthMode(DisplayPrefs.isStealthMode(this)
            && !ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction()));
    mLockPatternView.setOnPatternListener(mLockPatternViewListener);
    if (lastPattern != null && lastDisplayMode != null
            && !ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
        mLockPatternView.setPattern(lastDisplayMode, lastPattern);

    /*
     * COMMAND BUTTONS
     */

    if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "initContentView", 7000).show();
        mBtnCancel.setOnClickListener(mBtnCancelOnClickListener);
        mBtnConfirm.setOnClickListener(mBtnConfirmOnClickListener);

        mBtnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBtnConfirm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (infoText != null)
            mTextInfo.setText(infoText);
        else
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_draw_an_unlock_pattern);

        /*
         * BUTTON OK
         */
        if (mBtnOkCmd == null)
            mBtnOkCmd = ButtonOkCommand.CONTINUE;
        switch (mBtnOkCmd) {
        case CONTINUE:
            mBtnConfirm.setText(R.string.alp_cmd_continue);
            break;
        case DONE:
            mBtnConfirm.setText(R.string.alp_cmd_confirm);
            break;
        default:
            /*
             * Do nothing.
             */
            break;
        }
        if (btnOkEnabled != null)
           mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(btnOkEnabled);

    }// ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN
    else if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(infoText))
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_draw_pattern_to_unlock);
        else
            mTextInfo.setText(infoText);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_INTENT_ACTIVITY_FORGOT_PATTERN)) {
            mBtnConfirm.setOnClickListener(mBtnConfirmOnClickListener);
            mBtnConfirm.setText(R.string.alp_cmd_forgot_pattern);
            mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
            mFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
    else if (ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);

        final ArrayList<Cell> pattern;
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN))
            pattern = getIntent()
                    .getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN);
        else
            getIntent().putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                    EXTRA_PATTERN,
                    pattern = LockPatternUtils
                            .genCaptchaPattern(DisplayPrefs
                                    .getCaptchaWiredDots(this)));

        mLockPatternView.setPattern(DisplayMode.Animate, pattern);
    }// ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA
}// initContentView()

 * Encodes {@code pattern} to a string.
private char[] encodePattern(List<Cell> pattern) {

 * Compares {@code pattern} to the given pattern (
private void doComparePattern(List<Cell> pattern) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside doComparePattern", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (pattern == null)
        return;

    boolean okey = false;

    if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        char[] currentPattern = getIntent()
                .getCharArrayExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN);
        if (currentPattern == null)
            currentPattern = SecurityPrefs.getPattern(this);

        okey = Arrays.equals(encodePattern(pattern), currentPattern);
    }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
    else if (ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        final List<Cell> captchaPattern = getIntent()
                .getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN);
        okey = captchaPattern.size() == pattern.size();
        if (okey) {
            for (int i = 0; i < captchaPattern.size(); i++) {
                if (!captchaPattern.get(i).equals(pattern.get(i))) {
                    okey = false;
                    break;
                }
            }// for
        }
    }// ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA

    if (okey)
        finishWithResultOk(null);
    else {
        mRetryCount++;
        mIntentResult.putExtra(EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT, mRetryCount);

        if (mRetryCount >= mMaxRetry)
            finishWithNegativeResult(RESULT_FAILED);
        else {
            mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Wrong);
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_try_again);
            mLockPatternView.postDelayed(mLockPatternViewReloader,
                    DELAY_TIME_TO_RELOAD_LOCK_PATTERN_VIEW);
        }
    }
}// doComparePattern()

/**
 * Checks and creates the pattern.
 * 
 * @param pattern
 *            the current pattern of lock pattern view.
 */
private void doCheckAndCreatePattern(List<Cell> pattern) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside doCheckAndCreatePattern", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (pattern.size() < mMinWiredDots) {
        mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Wrong);
        mTextInfo.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.alp_pmsg_connect_x_dots, mMinWiredDots,
                mMinWiredDots));
        mLockPatternView.postDelayed(mLockPatternViewReloader,
                DELAY_TIME_TO_RELOAD_LOCK_PATTERN_VIEW);
        return;
    }

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN)) {
        if (Arrays.equals(getIntent().getCharArrayExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN),
                encodePattern(pattern))) {
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_your_new_unlock_pattern);
            mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);
            mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(false);
            mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Wrong);
            mLockPatternView.postDelayed(mLockPatternViewReloader,
                    DELAY_TIME_TO_RELOAD_LOCK_PATTERN_VIEW);
        }
    } else {
        getIntent().putExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN, encodePattern(pattern));
        mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_pattern_recorded);
        mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
    }
}// doCheckAndCreatePattern()

 * Finishes activity with {@link Activity#RESULT_OK}.
private void finishWithResultOk(char[] pattern) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside finishWithResultOk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
        mIntentResult.putExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN, pattern);
    else {
        /*
         * If the user was "logging in", minimum try count can not be zero.
         */
        mIntentResult.putExtra(EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT, mRetryCount + 1);
    }

    setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntentResult);

    /*
     * ResultReceiver
     */
    ResultReceiver receiver = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER);
    if (receiver != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
            bundle.putCharArray(EXTRA_PATTERN, pattern);
        else {
            /*
             * If the user was "logging in", minimum try count can not be
             * zero.
             */
            bundle.putInt(EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT, mRetryCount + 1);
        }
        receiver.send(RESULT_OK, bundle);
    }

    /*
     * PendingIntent
     */
    PendingIntent pi = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_OK);
    if (pi != null) {
        try {
            pi.send(this, RESULT_OK, mIntentResult);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(CLASSNAME, "Error sending PendingIntent: " + pi);
                Log.e(CLASSNAME, ">>> " + t);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    finish();
}// finishWithResultOk()

/**
 * Finishes the activity with negative result (
 * {@link Activity#RESULT_CANCELED}, {@link #RESULT_FAILED} or
 * {@link #RESULT_FORGOT_PATTERN}).
 */
private void finishWithNegativeResult(int resultCode) {
    if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
        mIntentResult.putExtra(EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT, mRetryCount);

    setResult(resultCode, mIntentResult);

    /*
     * ResultReceiver
     */
    ResultReceiver receiver = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER);
    if (receiver != null) {
        Bundle resultBundle = null;
        if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            resultBundle = new Bundle();
            resultBundle.putInt(EXTRA_RETRY_COUNT, mRetryCount);
        }
        receiver.send(resultCode, resultBundle);
    }

    /*
     * PendingIntent
     */
    PendingIntent pi = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_CANCELLED);
    if (pi != null) {
        try {
            pi.send(this, resultCode, mIntentResult);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(CLASSNAME, "Error sending PendingIntent: " + pi);
                Log.e(CLASSNAME, ">>> " + t);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    finish();
}// finishWithNegativeResult()

/*
 * LISTENERS
 */

private final LockPatternView.OnPatternListener mLockPatternViewListener = new LockPatternView.OnPatternListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPatternStart() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onPatternStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mLockPatternView.removeCallbacks(mLockPatternViewReloader);
        mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Correct);

        if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside action create pattern", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_release_finger_when_done);
            mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
            if (mBtnOkCmd == ButtonOkCommand.CONTINUE)
                getIntent().removeExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN);
        }// ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_draw_pattern_to_unlock);
        }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);
        }// ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA
    }// onPatternStart()

    @Override
    public void onPatternDetected(List<Cell> pattern) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onPatternDetected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            doCheckAndCreatePattern(pattern);
        }// ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            doComparePattern(pattern);
        }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            if (!DisplayMode.Animate.equals(mLockPatternView
                    .getDisplayMode()))
                doComparePattern(pattern);
        }// ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA
    }// onPatternDetected()

    @Override
    public void onPatternCleared() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onPatternCleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mLockPatternView.removeCallbacks(mLockPatternViewReloader);

        if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Correct);
            mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
            if (mBtnOkCmd == ButtonOkCommand.CONTINUE) {
                getIntent().removeExtra(EXTRA_PATTERN);
                mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_draw_an_unlock_pattern);
            } else
                mTextInfo
                        .setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);
        }// ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mLockPatternView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Correct);
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_draw_pattern_to_unlock);
        }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mTextInfo.setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);
            List<Cell> pattern = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(
                    EXTRA_PATTERN);
            mLockPatternView.setPattern(DisplayMode.Animate, pattern);
        }// ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA
    }// onPatternCleared()

    @Override
    public void onPatternCellAdded(List<Cell> pattern) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }// onPatternCellAdded()
};// mLockPatternViewListener

private final View.OnClickListener mBtnCancelOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finishWithNegativeResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }// onClick()
};// mBtnCancelOnClickListener

private final View.OnClickListener mBtnConfirmOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            if (mBtnOkCmd == ButtonOkCommand.CONTINUE) {
                mBtnOkCmd = ButtonOkCommand.DONE;
                mLockPatternView.clearPattern();
                mTextInfo
                        .setText(R.string.alp_msg_redraw_pattern_to_confirm);
                mBtnConfirm.setText(R.string.alp_cmd_confirm);
                mBtnConfirm.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                final char[] pattern = getIntent().getCharArrayExtra(
                        EXTRA_PATTERN);
                if (mAutoSave)
                    SecurityPrefs.setPattern(MainActivity.this,
                            pattern);
                finishWithResultOk(pattern);
            }
        }// ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN
        else if (ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            /*
             * We don't need to verify the extra. First, this button is only
             * visible if there is this extra in the intent. Second, it is
             * the responsibility of the caller to make sure the extra is an
             * Intent of Activity.
             */
            startActivity((Intent) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
                    EXTRA_INTENT_ACTIVITY_FORGOT_PATTERN));
            finishWithNegativeResult(RESULT_FORGOT_PATTERN);
        }// ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
    }// onClick()
};// mBtnConfirmOnClickListener

/**
 * This reloads the {@link #mLockPatternView} after a wrong pattern.
 */
private final Runnable mLockPatternViewReloader = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mLockPatternView.clearPattern();
        mLockPatternViewListener.onPatternCleared();
    }// run()
};// mLockPatternViewReloader
```

}

Comment: post only the relevant part not your whole project

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is in your initialization in initContentView().  You are setting btnOkEnabled before you've loaded the button into mBtnConfirm.

Move your findViewById() calls to the top of that method and you should be all set.

Comment: The button is still not working. I tried to display a toast onclick but no response from the button. please see my code and tell me the error. thankx in  advance